# ListView displays data from last passes as well as current pas

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapterview

I have a small "search" implementation I am working on. A listView displays the items if they match the query. This works fine, but whenever the menu is hidden and re-displayed and a new query is made, all the "searchables" continue to stack up. If i have 4 that should be displaying, first it would show 4, then 8, then 12, etc.

```
private class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Adapter(){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return menuItems.get(position).text;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return menuItems.get(position).id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            if (!isSearching) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbm_item, null);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbm_search_item, null);                 
            }
            holder.subMenuList = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_holder);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_text);  

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (holder.subMenuList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        holder.subMenuList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        holder.subMenuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (isSearching) {
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_icon);
                holder.image.setImageResource(menuItems.get(position).icon);    
                holder.chapterId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_text);
                holder.chapterId.setText("Ch"+Integer.toString(menuItems.get(position).id));
            } else {
                holder.chapterId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_id);
                holder.chapterId.setText(Integer.toString(menuItems.get(position).id));
            }
            holder.text.setText(menuItems.get(position).text);
            if (!isSearching) {
                for (int i=0;i<menuItems.get(position).subItems.size();i++) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(ctx);
                    tv.setTextColor(0xFF893658);
                    tv.setText(menuItems.get(position).subItems.get(i).getTitle());
                    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(menuItems.get(position).subItems.get(i).getIcon(), 0, 0, 0);
                    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (menuItems.get(position).subItems.size() == 1) {
                            tv.setPadding(20, 20, 0, 20);
                        } else{
                            tv.setPadding(20, 20, 0, 10);
                        }
                    } else if (i == menuItems.get(position).subItems.size()-1){
                        tv.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 20);
                    } else {
                        tv.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 10);
                    }
                    holder.subMenuList.addView(tv);
                }
            } 

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView image;
        LinearLayout subMenuList;
        TextView chapterId;
    }           
}
```

Comment: How are you putting the new searchable results in `menuItems`?

Comment: Where are you getting the menuitems from and what is it?

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are _always_ creating a new ListView item, you never use the adapter's recycler...

Comment: can you show the code how you are doing that

Comment: @Sam, correct. It was causing a lot of issues. Im reusing the list and the men and the adapter for a lot of different tasks. Removing that check was the only way for it to work. The list is never longer than 10 or so though so there shouldnt be a huge proformance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to clear the listitems that are in the menuItems and then add the items back after the new query is made.
Is the try to clear the listitems that are in the menuItems and then add the items back after the new query is made a arraylist or something?

Comment: when the menu is "shown", i clear all of the data from menuItems, i can try to clear them on query change though.

Comment: did you get solution for your problem?

Comment: ya. that was it. i had a text watcher, so id just clear the menu items each time the query string changed. seems like a bit overkill, but its working so i wont complain

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell for sure from what you posted, but I'd guess that you're appending the new results to menuItems rather than replacing it with your new data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem much. but by just glancing over your code i see one issue

```
if (!isSearching) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbm_item, null);
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbm_search_item, null);                 
        }
```

This piece can be the cause of your problem.
getView method of list adaptor gets called very frequently and so it should contain minimum and less heavy operation.

If you will going to check the default examples of list adapters. you will going to see the convertView is checked against null so that it need not to be inflated again and is reused again for faster preparation of view to be displayed in the list.
And this is not happening in your code.

Google about Efficient Adapter Example Android.